# How to logout with JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, logout

I am using JWT for authentication and authorization. But I don't know what to write in logout route. I have searched a lot but could not get what to fill in logout route. This is my code. Please help.

```
const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtKey="My_admin_is_safe";
app.get('/admin',(req,res)=>{
res.render('LoginAdmin',{erru:"",errp:""});
 });

 app.post('/admin/login',(req,res)=>{
  Admin.findOne({username:req.body.id},(function(err,result){
    if(!result)
        res.render('LoginAdmin',{erru:"Username not found",errp:""});
    else if(!passwordHash.verify(req.body.password,result.password))
        res.render('LoginAdmin',{erru:"",errp:"Incorrect Password"});
    else 
        {   const user=result.username;
            const token = jwt.sign({ user }, jwtKey, {
            algorithm: "HS256",
            })
            console.log("token:", token);

     // set the cookie as the token string, with a similar max age as the token
     // here, the max age is in milliseconds, so we multiply by 1000
                res.cookie("token", token);
                res.render('Main');
           }
           }))
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if I got your code right, I'm not seeing any signature mechanism applied to the JWT, which in general is considered best practice.

As you said correctly, you couldn't find any example of JWT logout because in fact there isn't any: once a valid JWT is handed to the client, it is considered valid for all the established TTL.
What you can do though, is adding some stateful logic to JWT token and memorize those in a Key-Value database (like Redis) and start building a blacklist and whitelist of published token. So that when you receive a request with a token you also verify if this hasn't been blacklisted before authorizing the client.

Comment: After searching a lot what I did is hashing the token generated using the password-hash package and storing it into an array. In my authorizing middleware, I am searching If the token exists in the array. After logout, I just remove that token from the array. Is it a good approach?

Comment: that's a good approach, although some words of cautions. Watch out for hashing limits in terms of chances of collision (not sure how many JWT you are going to handle with this code). Another important point is that you might want to persist the JWTs (using Redis or some other data storage) in case your program crashes. And you might still want to keep old JWTs (or a blaklist of those still valid), in case you are keeping the association with clients, so that you can do historical analysis on who are the most frequently malicious clients.